# Check if array contains number in Jep

Tags: java

I'm using this "Math Expression Parser" library from singularsys. Here's its documentation : [Official tutorials](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/doc/html/confparser.html)  and  [Documentation](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/doc/javadoc/index.html)

What I'm trying to do is this :

```
    Jep jep = new Jep();

    jep.addVariable("ARR", new int[]{1,2,3});
    jep.parse("ARR == 3");

    Object result = jep.evaluate();
    boolean ok = false;
    if(result != null)ok = Boolean.valueOf(result.toString());
    System.out.println(ok);
```

I've set a variable called `ARR` that contains the numbers 1, 2, and 3.
I need it to check if the Array contains the number 3, and return "true".

Any ideas what operator or function to use, or if that's even possible? I couldn't find anything in the documentation but I have a feeling it's doable somehow.

Comment: I am not familiar with this library but it looks that `jep.parse("ARR == 3");` is wrong. First you need to create vector , [Vector Example](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/doc/html/types.html) then use class Ele [Ele Class](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/doc/javadoc/index.html?com/singularsys/jep/functions/Ele.html) to find an Object in this vector. Method , `ele(java.lang.Object vec, java.lang.Object indexObject)` seems suitable for your need. You may like to tag your question with "singularsys" and "Jep" to get better response.

Comment: @Sabir_Khan: Thank you, I found a solution that works. See response bellow.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building a custom function :

```
public static class JepContains extends BinaryFunction
    {
      public Object eval(Object arg1, Object arg2)
      {
          int[] arr = (int[])arg1;
          int target = ((Double)arg2).intValue();         
          for(double i : arr)
              if(i==target)
                  return true;        
          return (Object)false;
      }
    }
```

Here's how I used it :

```
jep.addFunction("contains",new JepContains());
jep.addVariable("ARR", new int[]{1,2,3});
jep.parse("contains(ARR, 2)"); // returns "true"
```